# How to allow one single entry in a multi field entry form with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a data entry form which creates a row in another sheet from those data.

I then have to make another entry form where it is possible only to type in one of the specific data entries from the entry form before. That should then find all rows containing this specific entry and move these rows to a third sheet.

How do I specify that only one single entry is allowed in the entry form?

I thought about using:

```
If Not IsEmpty(Me.Textbox1.Value) then
   MsgBox "Only one entry is allowed"
End If
```

But of course this just locks the specific input box.

Thanks!

Comment: You can check all the Inputfields in the Userform and if more than one contains a value then you can pop this msgbox.

Comment: Can you show you userform pls ?

Answer (score 0):

Standard checks during a `commandbutton_click` event, which is above the rest of the scripting that would happen where this isn't true, would be a for each loop to check the controls in the form.  you can use a dummy variable to check how many textbox controls have values, similar to:

```
for each ctrl in me.controls
    if typename(ctrl) = "textbox" then 'important
        if ctrl.value <> "" then i = i+1
    end if
next ctrl
if i > 1 then 
    msgbox "don't be dumb"
    exit sub
end if
'insert code that runs when only 1 textbox is used
```

Comment: It says: Compile error. Variable not defined. 

I inserted this code:

Private Sub CommandButton_Indskriv_Click()

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "textbox" Then MsgBox "Koden virker. Kun en enkelt boks er udfyldt"
    If ctrl.Value <> "" Then i = i + 1
    End If
Next ctrl
If i > 1 Then
    MsgBox "don't be dumb"
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Comment: @TinoPetersson did you dimension your variables?   `Dim ctrl as control, i as long`?  Helps to indicate at which line it gives the error... (guessing it is ctrl or i)